# Does ModSecurity and CiviCRM play well together?

Tags: security

I am thinking to add ModSecurity to the server (Wordpress 5.x/Apache2/Ubuntu 18) that is running CiviCRM to further augment the security.  Thought I thought I check on this forum on the experience of doing so and whether it is a good idea.  Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've often run into trouble with shared hosts' use of ModSecurity, but those that are willing to tweak the rules have always managed to make it work.  Expect to do some testing!

Comment: Jon do you know if there are some generic CiviCRM rules or if it needs to be custom each time?

Comment: @herb I don't know - I've never been the one to make the change. I've wanted to implement mod_security for my own servers for a long time but haven't had time to learn the rule syntax (which is a lot).  Hit me up on Mattermost (@junglebird) if you're trying to implement it yourself, vs. dealing with a webhost! If you ARE dealing with a webhost, you basically need to know which URL is getting blocked, ideally with a date/time when it's happening.  The mod_security log will say which rule caused it.